# How to put Bootstrap accordion button before text and change it's style?

Tags: html, css, button, bootstrap-5, accordion

Here is link for bootstrap accordion with plus and minuses: https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=accordion-with-plus-minus-icon
How to put buttons as shown in this link: https://ibb.co/GJRGKnn

Also I want to change button's style as shown in this link: https://ibb.co/GPTGpp8

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please add this css and check agian.

```
.accordion-button::after {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
```